# liuggio/ExcelBundle is not supporting excel 2010

Tags: symfony, phpexcel, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

liuggio/ExcelBundle is supporting for Microsoft 2007, for 2010 it's not supporting. please help me to get the bundle for Symfony to support 2010 excel.

if liuggio/ExcelBundle this bundle itself supporting then kindly let me know the solution to follow the steps.

currently, I'm using liuggio/ExcelBundle @Version 1.8.1, 2015-04-30

Comment: The bundle is just a wrapper for `PHPExcel` so I suppose that you can use it with excel2010

BTW this kind of questions are not allowed on StackOverflow; I recommend you to read carefully the policy of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need bundle. You can install `PhpExcel` class and It is supporting 2007 and above.

Installation,

`composer require phpoffice/phpexcel`

Configuration and documentation,

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: Dear Mert Simsek 
composer require phpoffice/phpexcel using this if i just update my composer it will work ?
currently it is supporting for 2007 later it should not affect so
i am using below one in my symfony project  
liuggio/ExcelBundle @Version 1.8.1, 2015-04-30

Comment: composer require phpoffice/phpexcel if run this command existing functionalities will not affect right ?



it may silly doubt i am new to symfony so asking